# How to copy specific contents of a file onto another file in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I've been at this for hours now and I feel like I'm not getting some fundamental techniques in C. I've been trying to read in a specific line and store it into 2 separate files from one file. The source file (temp) is the one I'm reading in and the 2 files, data and text are the 2 files I'm trying to store.

TL;DR, how do I split up contents from a file into two separate file?

For example, the input file is:

```
.data
A: .word 32
B: .word 16

.text
main: 
la $s0 A 
lw $s0 0($s0)
la $s1 B
lw $s1 0($s1)
```

This function will take in the temp file and process the .data and .text segments into separate files.

```
void process_file(FILE * temp) 
{
    FILE * data, * text;

    char * token;
    char * nextLine;
    char line[256];
    char * str_token = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    char * str = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));

    int i;

    data = fopen("data.asm", "w");
    text = fopen("text.asm", "w");

    if (temp == NULL || data == NULL || text == NULL) 
    {
        printf("UNABLE TO OPEN OR LOCATE FILES. EXITING.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!feof(temp)) 
    {
        if ((nextLine = fgets(line, 256, temp)) != NULL) 
        {
            token = strtok(nextLine, "\n");
            //printf("%s", nextLine);

            if (token != NULL) 
            {   
                strcat(str_token, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, "\n");

                if ((strstr(str_token, ".data")) != NULL) 
                {
                    strcat(str, str_token);
                    fprintf(data, "%s", str); //ADDING THIS CAUSES A SEG FAULT :(
                }
                else if ((strstr(token, ".text")) != NULL) 
                {
                    fprintf(text, "%s", token);
                    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you keep appending to `str` and `str_token` without ever clearing them.  I'd guess eventually you write past the end of the allocated memory.  Are you just trying to write each line from .data until you hit the .text line to one file and the rest to the other?  It isn't clear what all the strtok stuff is for.

Comment: Use `strlcat()` instead of `strcat()`. It's safer and will help you avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: Are you stuck with the error or with routing the output?

Comment: More comments in your code, describing what it should do, would help.

Comment: Your `while (!feof(temp))` loop is wasteful of a level of indentation; you should remove the loop and change the `if` of `if ((nextline = fgets(line, 256, temp)) != NULL)` with `while`. You could forgo the `nextline` assignment too; the value will be equal to `line` (when it isn't null, but that's filtered out by the condition).

Comment: Here's a simplified version of what I think you're trying to do. http://ideone.com/u3bi9n  If all you're doing is writing each line to the proper file I don't see the need to tokenize anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void process_file(FILE *temp){
    FILE *data, *text, *fp;
    char line[256], str[256];
    char *token;

    data = fopen("data.asm", "w");
    text = fopen("text.asm", "w");

    if (temp == NULL || data == NULL || text == NULL) {
        printf("UNABLE TO OPEN OR LOCATE FILES. EXITING.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fp = data;//default for not start with .data and .text
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, temp)){
        strcpy(str, line);
        if((token=strtok(str, " \t\n"))!=NULL){//not blank line
            if(strcmp(token, ".data")==0)
                fp = data;
            else if(strcmp(token, ".text")==0)
                fp = text;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s", line);
    }
    fclose(data);
    fclose(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to get your answer, using the code you provided anyway

```
void process_file(FILE * temp) 
{
  //You may use NULL versus 0
  FILE * data = 0, * text = 0;

  char * token = 0;
  char * nextLine = 0;
  char line[256];

  int i = 0;

  data = fopen("data.asm", "w");
  text = fopen("text.asm", "w");

  if ( 0 == temp || 0 == data || 0 == text ) 
  {
      printf("UNABLE TO OPEN OR LOCATE FILES. EXITING.\n");
      exit(1);
  }

  while (!feof(temp)) 
  {
      if ((nextLine = fgets(line, 256, temp)) != NULL) 
      {
          token = strtok(nextLine, "\n");
          //printf("%s", nextLine);

          if (0 != token){   
              if(strcmp(token, ".data") == 0 ){
                 //Make use of that i
                 i = 1;
            }
            else if(strcmp(token, ".text") == 0){
                i = 2;
            }
            switch(i){
                case 1:
                    fprintf(data, "%s\r\n", token);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fprintf(text, "%s\r\n", token);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid!");
                    break;
               }
            }
        }
    }
fclose(data);
fclose(text);
fclose(temp);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void process_file(FILE * temp) 
{
FILE * data, * text, *write = NULL;

char * token;
char * nextLine;
char line[256];
char * str_token = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
char * str = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));

char val [] = "safasfsdf";
int i;
data = fopen("data.asm", "w");
text = fopen("text.asm", "w");


if (temp == NULL || data == NULL || text == NULL) 
{
    printf("UNABLE TO OPEN OR LOCATE FILES. EXITING.\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (!feof(temp)) 
{
    if ((nextLine = fgets(line, 256, temp)) != NULL) 
    {

    if ((strstr(line, ".data")) != NULL) 
    {
        write = data;
    }
    else if ((strstr(line, ".text")) != NULL) 
    {
        write = text;
    }

    if(line[0]!= '\n'){
        printf ("%p %s",write,  line);
            fprintf(write, "%s", line);
    }
    }
}


fclose (data);
fclose (text);

}
```

pattern is identified first. Based on the pattern file pointer is selected. I have removed the few unwanted line from the original source and make it simple. Hope this will be helpful to you.